# Trouble with NextJS & Firebase deployment API Routes

Tags: firebase, next.js

I'm creating a small project using NextJS (version 13.4.19) and Firebase. I created some basic APIs in `pages/api`. I deployed this small NextJS project using Firebase, but there is an issue when I try to make a request to this endpoints on the deployed site (this doesn't happen on local). The issue that comes out is `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` but I don't know where is the issue in the API.
The API looks like this:

```
type ResponseData = {
  message: boolean
}
 
export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>
) {
  try {
    if(req.method === "POST") {
      const {id, name} = req.body;
      if (id === 'abc' && name === 'joe') {
        res.status(200).json({ message: true });
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({ message: false });
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw res.status(500).json({ message: e });
  }
}
```

When calling the endpoint, I'm adding the `Content-Type` on the header.

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```